# Intercepting and re-writing a URL from third-party library

Tags: c#, http, url, get

We are using an third-party SDK to access a specialized medical device (which hosts a web server).  Unfortunately there is a small bug that makes it unusable.  Specifically, the SDK calls the wrong URL on the device in question.  The SDK calls `https://192.168.1.17:443//Calls/` when it should be `http://192.168.1.17:443/Calls/` (two slashes is wrong).

We tried bypassing the SDK and calling the web server directly, but the return value (json) has to be transformed into a proprietary format before it can be passed on, and only the SDK can do that.

We can control what server it calls, but not the commands it sends. I am trying to find out if we can set up some intermediary fake server which would intercept the call and return the result from the real server, replacing the extra slash in the request URL.  Is something like that possible in .NET?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create WCF service and rewrite dispatcher behavior to redirect your URI to valid one, or just pass this json as is through connection.

More you can read at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734665(v=vs.110).aspx